# OWA URL Parameter for attaching file

Tags: url-parameters, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to attach a file to Outlook Web Mail using outlook URL parameters? I have read some documentation regarding URL parameters, but I have not found a way to accomplish this.

Comment: URL parameters manage content returned from a web server. So, for example, if you had a web application running on a web server that returned a different file based on parameters, you could include links to those resources in an email body.

Actually attaching files this way would probably pose a security risk. Linking may be a slightly better strategy.

Comment: So .as I understand from reply there is no direct way of attaching files using URL parameters but instead you can embed a link of document returned by web server or a unc link in the email body ,is that correct understanding ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right Giyra. However, the UNC link would be problematic in most cases because email is received outside of your network. You'll need to be sure any resource you link has been exposed publicly on the Web, and a web server (cloud or your own) is the best way to do this dynamically.

Comment: In my case it would be mostly for internal ..meaning within network.anyways I will also check for webservices which can upload on my app server a and provide href in email.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible according to my knowledge.  OWA is not designed to be embedded or programmed.  You would need to use EWS, REST, or some other programmatic methods to interact with Exchange Server / Exchange Online.